# Twitch API : is it possible to retrieve device IDs of people currently watching a stream?

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

I know it's possible to get the twitch usernames of the people currently in the chat of a stream, by using `https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/STREAMERNAME/chatters` (even though I don't know if it's permitted)

However, I'm more interested in getting exactly the same information, but with the [device IDs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/insights/#counting-device-ids) instead, but I can't find any information on if it's possible or not. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you get the ids from usernames? Like [this](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/getting-user-ids/13806)

Comment: I'm actually looking for the ids of people watching that don't have an account.